# Fallback pool in yarn v2 "loose" mode

Tags: yarnpkg, yarnpkg-v2

From the [docs](https://yarnpkg.com/features/pnp#pnp-loose-mode) on the loose mode of yarn v2:

> Yarn ships with a "loose" mode which will cause the PnP linker to work in tandem with the node-modules hoister - we will first generate the list of packages that would have been hoisted to the top-level in a typical node_modules install, then remember this list as what we call the "fallback pool".
>
> At runtime, packages that require unlisted dependencies will still be allowed to access them if any version of the dependency ended up in the fallback pool (which packages exactly are allowed to rely on the fallback pool can be tweaked with pnpFallbackMode).

So where exactly is this "fallback pool" located? In `.yarn/cache`? I activated the loose mode in a project with many deps but couldn't spot any difference compared to the the previous state.

Answer (score 1):

In loose mode Yarn 2 do not install any new dependencies, it adds fallback resolutions only. The fallback pool is a set of resolutions that can be used by all of your dependencies, it is a data structure stored inside `.pnp.js` file in a `fallbackPool` property. All of your dependencies can access the dependencies that would have been hoisted to the root `node_modules` folder. Yarn 2 determines this by running `node_modules` installation strategy in-memory and getting the list of dependencies hoisted to the root `node_modules` folder.

Please note, that closely related configuration option to `pnpMode: loose` is a `pnpFallbackMode` option. `pnpFallbackMode` determines who is allowed to use fallback dependencies. By default only dependencies of a root project are allowed to use fallback dependencies and workspace dependencies are not allowed to do so. With `pnpFallbackMode: all` both root project and workspace dependencies can rely on fallback dependencies. And with `pnpFallbackMode: none` - fallback dependencies are not allowed to be used at all.

Loose mode is useful for migration to Yarn 2 PnP, since some packages in JavaScript ecosystem heavily rely on the fact that they can access packages hoisted to the top-level `node_modules`. Though they are relying on the fact they shouldn't, in loose PnP mode Yarn will only issue a warning and let these packages work, instead of throwing access violation error.

Loose mode is a hybrid between old `node_modules` and newer PnP installation scheme, meant for easier migration to PnP.